# Android Servlet generate images

Tags: android, servlets, canvas, jpeg

In a normal Servlet I can generate an image using this code:

```
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    int width = 200, height = 200;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    drawInside(g); // draw on g

    // return
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
    encoder.encode(image);
    out.close();
}
```

But Android does't support BufferedImage and Graphics, so I need to use something like this:

```
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    int width = 200, height = 200;
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas g = new Canvas(image);

    drawInside(g); // draw on g

    // ...
}
```

But Android also not support JPEGImageEncoder. How can i write the image to ServletResponse.getOutputStream()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/q7oysr45kSI/9w2K308ajPMJ) the answer:

```
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```